# How can I verify that a button has changed using selenium-webdriver(java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify with web-driver the when I click on the button "Add to Cart", it changes to the other Button "Remove from Cart".  All items on page with an add to cart and remove from cart buttons, have identical code(Which I believe is whats really throwing me off)

```
<button> class="tg-button tg-button--large ng-binding tg-button--primary" ng-click="toggleDeviceToShoppingCart(deviceCatalogItem)" ng-class="{'tg-button--primary': !deviceIsInCart(deviceCatalogItem)}">Add to Cart</button>

<button> class="tg-button tg-button--large ng-binding" ng-click="toggleDeviceToShoppingCart(deviceCatalogItem)" ng-class="{'tg-button--primary': !deviceIsInCart(deviceCatalogItem)}">Remove from Cart</button>
```

Any suggestions on how to verify that the button has indeed changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are not exactly the same.

First solution: `Add to Cart` button has class attribute that `Remove from Cart` button doesn't have - `tg-button--primary`

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tg-button.tg-button--large.ng-binding")); // get the button
String classAttributes = button.getAttribute("class"); // get the class attribute
if (classAttributes.contains("tg-button--primary")) {
    // "Add to Cart" button
}
else {
    // "Remove from Cart" button
}
```

Second solution: the text of the buttons is different

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tg-button.tg-button--large.ng-binding")); // get the button
String text = button.getText(); // get the text
if (text.contains("Add to Cart")) {
    // "Add to Cart" button
}
else {
    // "Remove from Cart" button
}
```

Comment: Thank you Guy, Second solution did the trick for me, the only thing I added was a bool(before), and an assert(after) to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
findElement(by.cssSelector("Your selector here"))
    .getAttribute("class")
    .contains("tg-button--primary");
```

if is true, is the firs button. If false, is the second.
I hope the syntax is right, I only program in Selenium using C#